# get value of the string which is a variable in if condition

Tags: jquery

```
if (("tp" + i.toString()  == "tp"+ j.toString())  
 && ("lft" + i.toString() == "lft" + j.toString())) {

}
```

i have made let `tp1` as a variable,but here it is comparing as string and i made this string as a variable

Comment: so you have variables like `tp1` and `tp2` is that the case?

Comment: please help me it is important for me

Comment: you simply can't access variables by concatenating string.... you need to use an object(key-value pair) based solution

Comment: and it is behaving as a variable ,but i have taken them as global variable

Comment: can you please send me an example ,and please do some changes in my if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  **[eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)**

Like this

```
var tp1 = eval("tp" + i);
```

or if it's a global variable you can use like this

```
var tp1=window["tp" + i];
```

Comment: thank you for guiding me,this is working in my program very well

Comment: if you are using eval please keep in mind that eval is evil during minification.